# How to downcast an array in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, downcast

I currently have a `Tile` class that extends a `Node` class, and want to downcast an array of Nodes to an array of Tiles like so:

```
class Node<T> {
  Node[] neighbours;
  private final T value;
}

class Tile extends Node {

  public Tile(Point value) {
    super(value);
  }

  Tile[] neighbours = (Tile[]) this.getNeighbours;
}
```

At the moment the compiler is throwing A ClassCastException and I do not know how to fix it.

I am not 100% familiar with inheritance, but I thought since Tile is a subclass this should be a safe casting from Nodes to Tiles.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: It is same rule as with `Tile child = (Tile) new Node();`. It wouldn't be typesafe to let `child` hold `Node` instance because it is possible that `Tile` has some methods/fields which `Node` doesn't. Lets say we call `child.setPropertyAddedInTile(valie)`, how that code should be executed on `Node` instance which doesn't have such *property*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Tile` is a sub-class of `Node`, all `Tile`s a `Node`s, but **not** all `Node`s a `Tile`s.

Therefore casting a `Node[]` to `Tile[]` is wrong, since **not** all `Node` arrays are `Tile` arrays.

For example, the following will throw `ClassCastException`:

```
Node[] nodes = new Node[10];
Tile[] tiles = (Tile[]) nodes;
```

On the other hand, the following will work:

```
Node[] nodes = new Tile[10];
Tile[] tiles = (Tile[]) nodes;
```

Comment: @ZacSanchez that depends on the use case. From the little code you posted, it's hard to say. When ans how is the `neighbours` variable initialized in the `Node` class? And why would you want an instance variable of the same name and (possibly) same data in the `Tile` sub-class?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a collection, for example something like:

```
class Node<T> {
    List<Node> neighbours;
    private T value;
}

class Tile extends Node {

    public Tile(String value) {
        super(value);
    }

    List<Tile> neighbours = this.neighbours.stream().filter(item -> item instanceof Tile).map(item -> (Tile) item).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```